# How to fetch table data which is currently present on screen using javascript and convert it into csv file

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, sqlite

### after applying filter in table there are 4 enteries present.How can we store this data and convert it into csv.Currently i am able to dowload full table data using python code.But now i want to fetch and dowload the csv of data which is present on the screen.

========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getTableDataFn() {
    //we can use any of the get methods based on what we want
    let reqTable = document.getElementById("tableId");

    //Get rows
    let rows = reqTable.rows.length;

    //Get columns
    let columns = 0;
    if (rows > 0)
        columns = reqTable.rows[0].cells.length;

    let dataInArray = [];

    let strVersionOfData = ``;

    //Loop through row and column to get data in the object
    for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        dataInArray[r] = [];
        for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            let tempData = reqTable.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
            dataInArray[r][c] = tempData;
            strVersionOfData += tempData;
            if (c != columns - 1)
                strVersionOfData += ",";
        }
        strVersionOfData += "\n";
    }

    //Now the dataInArray has all the data and
    //strVersionofData has the string

 downloadCSVStringFn(strVersionOfData,'mycsv');

}
```

The above mentioned code might help you to get the data in array and string format. Now if you want to get your csv content downloaded in a file with name you can go by below mentioned function

```
function downloadCSVStringFn(fileName = "", csvString = "") {

    //Encode CSV data
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvString);
    //Create link 
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    //set attributes
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName + ".csv");
    //Append in document
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
    //Click .. this will download 
    link.click();

    //you can further delete the link too .. or have this is a component in case
    //you have download as a reusable utility
}
```

Comment: link is not showing for download.Sorry I am new to js

Comment: csvString  what do ihave to write in it

Comment: how to get a link in the above image to dowload the csv of the same function you have created.It is For storing data in csv and then using for ml analysis

Comment: suppose you have a button .. on click of the same just call getTableDataFn() .. I have updated the answer, the function call will now also download the file.

Comment: failed to dowload data (No file) when running

Comment: I am getting data in  strVersionOfData but it is not able to dowload the link